# Xamarin highlight cells in listview when cells are being reused

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I have a simple listview that shows client name and age. The list needs to be scrolled and I made the rows' background alternate colour (white and blue). But if the cell containing the client's age is 18, I want to highlight in orange and I want to highlight in red if the age is negative (to signal there is an error).
It all works fine until I start scrolling. At that point everything is messed up amd the orange/red background is not applied correctly. 
The adapter code is below. While debugging I noticed that the variable *position* changes value at each iteration. For example if I initially show only 8 rows, after scrolling I see that position goes to 9, 10... then 5, 4... I understand it might be because it is reusing rows but how can I make it work as expected? I hope someone can help since I tried many time but still didn't succeed. Thank you.

```
class MyListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<dbClient>
{
    public List<dbClient> mItems;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mRowLayout;
    private string[] mAlternatingColors;

    // Default constructor
    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<dbClient> items, int rowLayout)
    {
        mItems = items;
        mContext = context;
        mRowLayout = rowLayout;
        mAlternatingColors = new string[] { "#F2F2F2", "#00bfff" };
    }

    // Tells how many rows are in the dataset
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mItems.Count; }
    }

    // Return a row identifier
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    // Return the data associated with a particular row
    public override dbClient this[int position]
    {
        get { return mItems[position]; }
    }

    // Return a view for each row
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false);
        }

        row.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(mAlternatingColors[position % mAlternatingColors.Length]));

        TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameView);
        txtName.Text = mItems[position].Name;

        TextView txtAge = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ageView);
        txtAge.Text = mItems[position].Age.ToString();

        // highlight if aged 18
        if(txtAge.Text == "18")
        { txtAge.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Orange); }
        // signale there is error in the age reported
        if(txtAge.Text.Contains("-"))
        { txtAge.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red); }



        return row;
    }

    private Color GetColorFromInteger(int color)
    {
        return Color.Rgb(Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any problem?

Answer (score 0):

> It all works fine until I start scrolling. At that point everything is messed up amd the orange/red background is not applied correctly.

You're right that it reuses rows, so in your code, you changed color for different reasons and you didn't change it back to your original color. Just need to change part of your code in `GetView` for example like this:

```
// highlight if aged 18
if (txtAge.Text == "18")
{ txtAge.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Orange); }
// signale there is error in the age reported
else if (txtAge.Text.Contains("-"))
{ txtAge.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red); }
// set back to default color
else
{
    txtAge.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
}
```